# Key swapping but only for some keyboards

Tags: keyboard

(I'm on Arch Linux)

I want to swap `esc` and `capslock` but only do so for my laptop's built-in keyboard and not my plugged in extra keyboard. Is such a thing possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Today, basically all keyboards (even laptop built-in keyboards) identify as [HID devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) towards the kernel. You can check this for your laptop using `dmesg` after boot.

There's a very little known feature in the HID kernel layer which allows to map **scan codes** (a number assigned to each key, potentially different for different keyboards) to **key codes**.

I do not know of a single readily-available command line utility for this, but it is integrated into `udev` in form of a hardware database.

And fortunately this database is by device, so it fits exactly your use case: You can have key swapping for one keyboard, but not the other.

Details can be found e.g. [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes), or google "udev hwdb" or similar. Setting everything up will require time and fiddling.